# Can not remote connect to RDS DB instance of AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, remote-connection

I have a problem with connect to DB instance of AWS after I config that:

http://www.test.htmlcssworld.com/CDN/rds-dashboard.png

I already add this DB instance to the Security Group with RULE: MySQL - TCP - port:3306 and source is Anywhere.

http://www.test.htmlcssworld.com/CDN/cmd-rds.png

But when I try to remote connect via CLI that show error (10060).

Note: All of them i manipulation at US West (Oregon) and have Security Group Rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things to check

- Security group (you did that already, looks good)
- Subnet is public ?  i.e. it has a Routing Table that includes a Rule that says 0.0.0.0/0 DST Internet Gateway
- Internet Gateway is attached to your VPC

On a side note, I would strongly discourage to make your database publicly available on the internet.  In an ideal world, your database must have only a private IP address and must be available only from your app servers.  Should you really need to be able to access your database from the Internet, your Security Group should be restricted to a /32 IP address

Answer (score 0):

Oh My God!

My problems is: Subnet is public ? i.e. it has a Routing Table that includes a Rule that says 0.0.0.0/0 DST Internet Gateway.

Thank you to Sébastien Stormacq very much.

I follow to this document that never mention about this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/wah-linux/getting-started-deploy-app.html

It drive me crazy, but now I can connect to it easily.

Thank you again <3!

Comment: This tutorial focuses on the DB and App Server components, not too much into the networking parts.  It however says "Select your VPC from Network and select one of your public subnets from Subnet." http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/wah-linux/getting-started-application-server.html