# Creating a database link from AWS EC2

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, linked-server

Our staging database is stored on Amazon Web Services EC2.  I'm trying to create a database link from the server to an external database because, unfortunately, there's data in another system that we have to join our tables with, and it has to stay there.

On my local I can create a linked database easily [in SSMS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx).  But I can't do that for staging because AWS [doesn't allow](http://sebastiantoet.com/2013/04/04/some-important-gotchas-when-starting-with-amazon-rds-sql-server/) any users to have the sysadmin role.  Supposedly AWS lets you do some things through it that the sysadmin role can do, but I can't find a definitive list anywhere for that.

Is there anyway to created linked servers in AWS?

Comment: Are you using RDS, or SQL Server installed on your own EC2 instance?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server Management Studio on my computer and accessing the EC2 server/databases from there.

Comment: AWS didn't limit the permission and provide system role for your own ec2 instance. It is your responsible to make it work. In your case, mostly it is the firewall setting. Review and Work on `security group` and assign proper security group to that ec2 instance will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As per comment to your question, your issue is probably linked to network access.
See this question for a checklist of items to verify in terms of network connectivity : 
[Can not remote connect to RDS DB instance of AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27778263/can-not-remote-connect-to-rds-db-instance-of-aws/27781431#27781431)